# Tool for Firefox like Chrome's Timeline

Tags: performance, firefox, profiling, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a tool similar to Chrome's Timeline ? I don't mean the Net tab in Firebug ... I mean this : 
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline.

What do you use for Performance profiling in FF? I tried the FF Profiler but it's not nearly as helpfull as what Chrome has.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox's profiler will get an significant update in 34.0, so if you're willing to run [Aurora](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/channel/#aurora), give it a try.

[image: New Performance]

Here are the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Performance

Answer (score 2):

Expect a lot more performance related tools in the coming versions of Firefox.

We've been working on a new timeline that reports Gecko (firefox's rendering engine) operations like style calculations, layout, paints. It's in Nightly right now and needs to be turned on from the options panel.
It's pretty similar to what the Chrome devtools provides.

It's still experimental for now (that's why it's behind a pref) and will move around quite a bit in the coming months, but it's a start.

[image]